# Image comparison using MATLAB

Tags: computer-vision, matlab

I want to compare a bunch of depth images coming from Kinect and eliminate the similar ones. Those images present posture of a single user sitting on the chair (depicted in).

[image]

My idea is to create a function which will return the difference in range [0,1] between two postures. This means, I want to compare only a posture for given two images (a grey region). For example, if I pass [images](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9ZvXx6KMw-U/T5APMXqWT_I/AAAAAAAAAfE/jXZnQK04TVw/s940/image1_image2.jpg) to my function, the result will be 0 (because postures are the same, but not at the same position on the picture).

Hence, I need to modify the following code (and find something to replace "correlation"):

```
a = imread('image_user_depth_000041.jpg');  %first img
b = imread('image_user_depth_000042.jpg');  %second img
a = RGB2IND(a,16);
b = RGB2IND(b,16);

c = corr2(a,b);           %finding the correlation 
if c==1
 disp('The images are same') % display
else
 disp('the images are not same')
end;
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
My regards and thanks!

Comment: It would benefit you to look into machine learning, more specifically neural networks. What you are looking at is a classification. 1 if this pattern matches what I am looking for. 0 if this pattern doesn't. Andrew Ng has a free course on it. Google coursera for more detail.

Comment: @CyberMen, Machine learning is not the way to go about this kind of problems. You can't built/train an accurate classifier that does that. You will only make things more complicated for no reason.

Comment: Could you post or upload+link the two original images? I'd like to test out some code on them. Thanks!

Comment: How did you the get the depth images from Kinect ?? I need it for my project.. please help me out

Answer (score 6):

You can borrow from techniques used by the image stitching community, where they have to deal with [registering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) translated and rotated images. Your mistake was that you calculated the correlation before finding the optimal translation. [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) should give you enough information to help yourself.

### Mathematica Example

First, I split the picture above into `frame1.png` and `frame2.png`. Then I shifted the second one to align with the first, and trimmed both to retain their intersection. Finally, I compute the correlation coefficient by flattening the matrix into a vector.

```
img1 = ColorConvert[Import["frame1.png"], "Grayscale"]
img2 = ColorConvert[Import["frame2.png"], "Grayscale"]
im2t = ImageAlign[img1, img2, "Transformation" -> "Translation"]
imgtr = FindGeometricTransform[img1, img2, "Transformation" -> "Translation"]
{trx, try} = Part[TransformationMatrix@Last@imgtr, {1, 2}, 3]
{trim1, trim2} = ImageTake[#, {1, Floor@try}, {1, Floor@trx}] & /@ {img1, im2t}
{cimg1, cimg2} = Flatten@First@ImageData[#, "Interleaving" -> False] & /@ {trim1, trim2};
Correlation[cimg1, cimg2]
```

The result I got was **0.967834**, indicating a close match. If necessary I would have considered scaling and rotation to better align the images but it was not necessary here.

[Here](https://thilinasameera.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/translation-invariant-image-registration-using-phase-correlation-panorama-imaging-on-matlab/) is a MATLAB example.

Comment: "FindGeometricTransform" = wow. Mathematica. You've convinced me to switch